# Copied Google Drive Video API Low Quality

Tags: google-drive-api

Some of my copied video file from google drive are low quality and won't encode anymore. Is there any way to copy it without re-encoding again?. There's no documentation related to that. their might be a trick you know.

Here's my current copy code. It works just fine

```
 public function copy($srcId, $fileName)
   {
      $file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
      $file->setName($fileName);
      $file->setDriveId($this->sharedDriveId);
      $file->setParents(array($this->sharedDriveId));

      $newFile = $this->service->files->copy($srcId, $file, $this->applyDefaultParams([
         'fields' => $this->fetchfieldsGet,
         'supportsAllDrives' => true,
         'supportsTeamDrives' => true,
      ], 'files.copy'));

      return $newFile;
   }
```

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to stack please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  Edit your question include your code describe any issues you are having with your code.

Comment: Nothing in that code appears to have any possible special cases for video, much less that it would automatically transcode the files. Are you sure that is not just how the files are stored on the Drive? For example, if you download through the browser, aren't they the same?

Comment: I am sure, since, I have tried to multiple my files 3 times to make a backup. And one of the file got the right quality while the other copied 2 file is not on the right quality. It's been a day.